# What is missing within my javascript for a disappearing navbar?

Tags: javascript

I want to avoid jQuery so I can get a better feel for Javascript.  For now I have a Codepen set up that displays a large majority of my first project.  I know the code is probably sloppy and I am a beginner. I simply want to get the JS working with my navbar completely disappearing onScroll then I will optimize it from there. Thanks!

I have searched youtube, google, SO but everyone seems to use jQuery.

https://codepen.io/dev20tx/pen/wbKyJq

The CSS:

```
.nav {
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
text-align: right;
height: 70px;
line-height: 70px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 2;
}
```

And the Javascript:

```
window.onscroll = function() {navFunction()};

function navFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.queryselector(".nav").className = "test";
  } else {
    document.queryselector(".nav").className = "";
  }
}
```

Disappearing navbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the codepen at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgOdXy

Following is the updated JavaScript code, first problem was that you was attaching event listener to `window`, instead of the element which is to be scrolled and second mistake was the spelling mistake of `querySelector` method

```
function navFunction(e) {
  if (e.target.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.querySelector(".nav").className = "nav test";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".nav").className = "nav";
  }
}

document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("scroll",navFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

Allright, so, few things.

First, `queryselector` should be `querySelector` (with a capital S). Also note that setting the `.nav`'s `className` to `"test"` or `""` will remove the `"nav"` class from that element.

Second, you should make sure you attach the onscroll event *after* the page has loaded.

Lastly, you're attaching the onscroll event to the window, but you actually want to attach it to the `.container` element, as that's the element you're scrolling.

I'm not just throwing the entire solution in your lap, as you seem to want to play around yourself a little bit. If you do want a more elaborate answer, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I can't believe I did not capitalize that.  Thanks, between your answer and the one below I realize my mistakes.